# how can I control the permissions of files generated by gcc in linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, file-permissions

The sources for my code all belong to the unix group `group1`:

```
> ls -l *c
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 group1 4976 Nov  9 13:42 commands.c
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 group1 2347 Nov  9 13:42 env_list.c
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 group1 2468 Nov  9 13:42 job_list.c
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 group1 4453 Nov  9 13:42 jobs.c
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 group1 3278 Nov  9 13:42 smash.c
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 group1 2151 Nov  9 13:42 variable.c
```

`gcc` belongs to `group2`:

```
> ls -l gcc
-rwxrwsr-x  1 toolsusr group2 72 Dec 30  2008 /usr/intel/pkgs/gcc/4.3.2/bin//gcc
```

For some reason, when I compile, all of the targets are marked as belonging to `group2`.  However, when I compile a similar project, the targets remain under `group1`.

How can I control the group (and while I'm at it, any other permissions) of the generated files?

I am using gcc 4.3.2 and this version of Linux: `x86-64_linux_2.6.5_ImageSLES9SP3-3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the *stick bit* of the directory you are compiling in.  If set, it will make all of the files written to that directory have the same group of the directory itself.  If it is not set, they will have the default group of the user who is writing the file (the user who ran gcc).
You can use

```
chmod +t dir
```

to add the sticky bit to a directory.

**Comment**:

It's not the sticky bit, but rather the setguid bit:

```
chmod +s dir
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem.  This is my `ls -l` of the relevant directory: `drwxr-x--T  9 user1 group1 16384 Nov  9 23:38 ../i386_linux26/` but it still gets gcc's permissions

Comment: @Ignacio: `setgid` did the job. Would you care to add your own answer so I can upset it, or @KeithB, would you care to update your answer?

Comment: I'm accepting this even though the answer is wrong, because the comments are correct

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` doesn't concern itself with ownership of the files. If you need to modify the ownership or permissions of the generated files then you should do so in your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

For user/group updates, put it in your makefile (although it is impossible to change the user unless you are root or you run something like `cp` as a different user).

For `rwx` permissions, run `uname` before running `gcc`.